# Invalid date DatePicker

Tags: angularjs, date, datepicker

I'm pretty stucked on this problem where I have an API that return some data, in this format

```
{
  "data": {
    "result": [
      {
        "start_date": "03-08-2017 00:00:00",
        "end_date": "01-09-2017 23:59:59"
      },
      {
        "start_date": "01-01-2017 00:00:00",
        "end_date": "31-12-2017 23:59:59"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to take these data and make them modifiable by the user, so basically my HTML is something like that:

```
<table class="table" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-order">{{'START_DATE'| translate}}</th>
            <th class="col-order">{{'END_DATE'| translate}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <tr ng-repeat="row in insSupplies">
            <td>
                <exa-datepicker model="insSupplies[$index].start_date" disabled="true"
                            format="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" readonlydata="false"></exa-datepicker>
            </td>
            <td>
                <exa-datepicker model="insSupplies[$index].end_date" disabled="true"
                            format="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" readonlydata="false"></exa-datepicker>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and my JavaScript:

```
CallToTheAPI.then(function(response) {
  if(response.data != null){
    $scope.insSupplies = response.data.data.result;
  };
});
```

and my view is like that 
[image]

I see 2 problems here:

- hours are "casted" in a way I don't want, iterating them and adding 1 hours is not an option due to complexity of code (this is a sample)
- I don't get the sense of that invalid date

any help?

Comment: What is `exa-datepicker`? Can you link project page?

Comment: exa-datepicker is a custom picker used by this project, and it doesn't have an online doc, you can consider it just any other bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: You are getting time 1 hour ahead probably beacuse the dates are interpreted as UTC instaed of local time. It's hard to give you more info without `exa-datepicker` code, I think that the issue is the way `exa-datepicker` parses `model` values.